# Set vim indentation setting based on local styleguide file

Tags: vim, eslint

So my vim instance defaults to using 4 spaces per tab for most of my development purposes. But lets say I cd into a project like the following

```
.
├── .eslintrc
└── src
    ├── bar.js
    └── foo.js
```

and the `.eslintrc` file specifies a indentation setting of 2 spaces.

```
/* .eslintrc */

{
    "indent": ["error", 2]
}
```

How can I configure vim to automatically change to the indentation setting defined in the local `.eslintrc` file?

Answer (score 3):

Vim does not understand the format of `.eslintrc`. Somehow, this needs to be translated into the corresponding Vim commands (`:set ts=... sw=...` for example).

## Editor-independent settings

The [editorconfig.org](http://editorconfig.org/) project aims to establish a common format for coding styles that can be converted into the corresponding configuration for various IDEs and editors.

## Define directory-tree specific configuration in Vim

#### Central configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

#### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

#### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>

## Auto-detection instead of duplicated configuration

Most editing will be of existing files, created in an IDE or from a file template. For these, there are plugins that can detect the used indent settings, and adapt Vim's option accordingly. My [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) does that and also complains about inconsistent indents. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)